# How do I find an exact word and not part of a word?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - How to search for exact word match using LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743177/mysql-how-to-search-for-exact-word-match-using-like)

For example, if Im trying to get rows with the word "ever", I could do this...

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE `title` LIKE %ever%
```

But that would also give me results for titles with the words "forever, however, never".

How can I find only the titles which contain "ever" as its own word?

Comment: There is already a question with answers to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743177/mysql-how-to-search-for-exact-word-match-using-like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) regular expression to match using word boundaries `[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]` around your search term:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `title` REGEXP '[[:<:]]ever[[:>:]]'
```

Note that this is case-insensitive by default. For case sensitivity, you need to match it in `BINARY` mode:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `title` REGEXP BINARY '[[:<:]]ever[[:>:]]'
```

Since it cannot make use of indexing, performance can be quite poor on large tables however.

**Edit**: Sorry I had PCRE boundaries in there, which MySQL doesn't support.

Comment: I'd note that this'd be nasty on a large table, too.

Comment: @NiLe If you are satisfied with at least one occurance of `ever` within the string, you may do a [`instr`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php) e.g. `select * from table where instr(title,'ever') > 0;` `instr` returns first occurnace of a string within a string. ;) @MichaelBerkowski in terms of performance wise `instr` goes a bit faster than `regex` for a large table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) and the `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` word-boundary markers:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE keywords REGEXP '[[:<:]]ever[[:>:]]'
```