# Exact match of numbers

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have an issue with my regexp.
I have searched the site and found this example: [MySQL - How to search for exact word match using LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743177/mysql-how-to-search-for-exact-word-match-using-like)

this works a bit.

in my MYSQL database i have a lot of imported XML feed values in the column "Size"
like:

19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26

19;20;21;23

21

20-21-24

now if i want to find 21 then

```
    Size RLIKE '[[:<:]]21[[:>:]]'
```

works for some but not for all, I tried REGEXP, Like %21%
but nothing works.

when i try this example: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?30ko7
that seems to work but the REGEXP '/\b21\b/g' doesn't work when i try it.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `RLIKE '[[:<:]]21[[:>:]]'` is returning true for all the examples you've listed. Specify for which strings it doesn't match.

Comment: Hello anubhava, its not returning any values for 19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26 for me.

Comment: Using [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) would be better if you [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) the `|` with `,` first: `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('21', REPLACE('19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26', '|', ','));` though if you could normalize your database it would be easier still

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think i will str_replace the values when writing them to the database and then use FIND_IN_SET()