# Laravel search for specific word

Tags: php, laravel

I want to search for specific word instead of letter from a table. Right now i'm using `like` but it not like expected:

```
//  Category Table
-----------------------------------------------------
| id       |   amount           |  updated_at       |
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 1        | Bread              |2016-02-10 13:17:29|  
| 2        | Bread Loaf         |2016-02-10 13:17:29|
| 3        | Bread1             |2016-02-10 13:17:29|
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

For example I search for word "bread":

```
$words = "bread";
$query = Category::where(function ($query) use ($words) {
              $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $words . '%');
         })->get();
```

The result: all bread is coming out.

What I expected is "Bread1" is not get query. Only Bread and Bread Loaf.

What should I add to my query?

Comment: You may want to try this SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name RLIKE "[[:<:]]bread[[:>:]]"; [Same Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743177/mysql-how-to-search-for-exact-word-match-using-like)

Comment: Essentially this is evaluated as `WHERE name LIKE '%bread%'` meaning it will match anything with bread in it.  It doesn't evaluate it as a word. If you just added spaces, it would not match anything that starts or ends in bread.  John Roca gave a good solution with regex.

Comment: @JohnRoca thanks. it working

Comment: @SSuhat you can mark my answer as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name RLIKE "[[:<:]]bread[[:>:]]"; [Same Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743177/mysql-how-to-search-for-exact-word-match-using-like)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Eloquent you can do this like below.

```
$query->where('name', 'RLIKE ', "[[:<:]]"$words"[[:>:]]");
```

In raw query you can search it like this.

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name RLIKE "[[:<:]]categoryNameHere[[:>:]]";
```