# PHP MySQL search word if %100 equals to word I searched "bat" and I saw "batman" in results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

PHP MySQL search word if %100 equals to word I searched "bat" and I saw "batman" in results. I just want to list if title contains "bat", I dont want to list if contains "batman"

I'm tried many way. I can't solve this problem. How can be solve this problem? I can't understand why result like that. This code in the below. Thanks for your advice from now.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `title` LIKE '%bat%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;";
```

Comment: `%` symbol means that any characters can be placed instead of it. Searching for `%bat%` means _find all strings that contain `bat` in them_.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `title` = 'bat' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;"; If you want the exact result, don't use like.

Comment: If you only want title equat to "bat" why you don't do `WHERE title = bat` ?

Comment: You don't need to use like here. you can simple use equal to(title = bat) in your query.

Comment: @MickaelLeger he did not say `equal to "bat"` but contains `bat`.

Comment: You need to use a Regular Expression, `'\bcat\b'`, I don't know if MySQL's REGEXP supports that syntax.

Comment: "_I just want to list if title contains "bat", I dont want to list if contains "batman"_" but ... "batman" *does* contain the word "bat"!?!

Comment: @Berk : I'm not sure to understand, there is a difference between "contain" and "equal 100%", if you want "contain" why `batman` is not good? You want only `bat` or `**bat**`, `bat***`, `***bat`?

Comment: The OP appears to want 'Year of the bat' and 'The bat sat on a cat' but not 'Battleships'. That said, I agree that the OP has not been clear in this respect

Comment: @Strawberry ok, that's clear now ! He should edit is question because it's confusing :)

Comment: I show example with one word. But I use multiple words if I do "WHERE title = bat night" don't work. If I do this "WHERE `title` LIKE '%bat%night%'" work but in results available "batman" :(

Comment: Please edit your question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want title equal to the WORD "bat" :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `title` = 'bat' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;";
```

Now if you want title that contain the word "bat" but not the words that contain it, you can try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` 
        WHERE `title` LIKE '% bat %' 
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;";
```

or using `REGEXP`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` 
        WHERE `title` RLIKE '[[:<:]]bat[[:>:]]' 
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;";
```

But in this case, it's a duplicate of this question : [MySQL - How to search for exact word match using LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743177/mysql-how-to-search-for-exact-word-match-using-like)

Comment: OP wants search word to present in title, not title to be equal to the search word.

Comment: He wants "search word if % 100 equals to word", if he searches "bat" he doesn't want "batman" but only title with "bat", so why `title = 'bat'` is not good?

Comment: There is a small discussion under question that confirms my statement. You can edit your answer to account those clarifications.

Comment: Yeap, it's work. Thank you very much.    ` WHERE `title` LIKE '% bat % night %'`

Comment: @Berk glad to help you, but your question was a duplicate of other question :)

Comment: @lolbas You were right, I edited my anwser and it works, it was a duplicate of the question you wrote in the comment

Comment: @MickaelLeger yeah, sorry. I searched many times. I can see this question now.

Comment: @Berk np it happen ! I'd just like not to lose some of my few points with an helping anwser ^^

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a Regular Expression to match the exact word `bat`:

```
where `title` REGEXP '[[:<:]]bat[[:>:]]'
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are *word boundaries*, `bla bat, bla` passes, `batman` and `abat`will not pass